# Apache very slow when i update source

Tags: php, apache, debian

i am currently working on a CMS in PHP, and when i do some var_dump and echos to see if my code is working the output in the browser does not change, so i removed everything in the index.php and wrote echo time(); but the browser output was the same as before, so i checked via SSH if index.php on the server actualy changed, it did. It took about 2 minutes until the browser showed the unix timestamp, but the timestamp does change when i refresh the page every second....

i tired to open the page on another browser and then on another notebook that could not possibly have cached the site....still the same.

It looks like Apache needs some time to realize that the file has changed, but i have no idea why...it worked a few days ago...

any help is very appreciated!

Comment: What different cache systems do you have in place? expires headers? local storage? broswer caching? APC opcode? proxy in front of app?

Comment: How did you solve this? Having same issue

Answer (score 0):

It's rather on the browser side. Just add to your HTML header:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

should help :)